# How to construct nested UI elements in Xamarin.Mac and Xcode to bind to nested view models

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I am moving my application development from WPF via Xamarin.Forms to Xamarin.Mac.

I have a nested view model structure with view models exposing child view models via properties. Nested UI elements are bound to the view model properties exposed by the containing view model.

For example:

- ViewModel_1 bound to View_1

  - ViewModel_11 bound to View_11
  - ViewModel_12 bound to View_12

These view models are the DataContext of nested UserControls in WPF and the BindingContext of nested ContentViews in Xamarin.Forms.

What is the corresponding approach when working with Xamarin.Mac? I am not asking about the specifics of data binding (though I will need to get a handle on this), more the UI structure. Is it done by using nested view controllers? Nested views?

I am using Xcode Interface Builder to construct the UI.

If I am barking up the wrong tree, what is the right approach?

Comment: The closest equivalent to usercontrols I can think of is nibs, have you looked into these yet?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I am after is a Container View. Tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/704-macos-view-controllers-tutorial).

> A container view is a placeholder for another view and comes with its own View Controller.